# How to add order by in string agg, when two columns are concatenated

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT string_agg( distinct a || '-' || b , ',' ORDER BY a,b) 
FROM table;
```

The above sql giving error

> ERROR: in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: Please show your table structure.  Do you plan to do any grouping in your query as well?

Comment: No Grouping, its a plan query which concatenates two columns. My query is like above same query.

Comment: What the error message says: you must order by the expression that you aggregate.

Comment: I'm wondering if `SELECT distinct a || '-' || b as ab ORDER BY ab` would work?

Answer (score 4):

For [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

> If DISTINCT is specified in addition to an order_by_clause, then all the ORDER BY expressions must match regular arguments of the aggregate; that is, you cannot sort on an expression that is not included in the DISTINCT list.

So try

```
select string_agg(distinct a || '-' || b, ',' order by a || '-' || b)
from a_table;
```

or use `distinct` in a derived table:

```
select string_agg(a || '-' || b , ',' order by a, b)
from (
    select distinct a, b
    from a_table
    ) s;
```